# OData Function Import Exporting String

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, netweaver

I created an OData Service in the transaction SEGW. Then i added an Function Import with 2 import parameters. Inside the function import there is generated an String including the 2 parameters. I set an external breakpoint to the function import and tested it with /IWFND/GW_CLIENT and it works correctly. But now i want to pass that generated String as an export parameter. So when i call the function import in SAP WEB IDE i want to pass the two parameters and get the generated string. My problem is i don't know how to implement an export parameter or how to pass that string.

[Screenshot of the function import declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4IsF.png)

Comment: I think your odata service is somehow wrong. do not use function, you can can redefine odata services methods directly. check this tutorial: https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/06/let-s-code-crudq-and-function-import-operations-in-odata-service/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I took a look at the tutorial but it was not exactly what i was searching for. I went another way and created a database table in the backend system where the function import stores the created string and with a seccond OData Service i read the values from that table to work with it in SAP WEB IDE. It's maybe not the best way but it's working for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a Complex Type

[image]

and set this complex type as an export parameter in your function import definition.

[image]

In the redefined "execute_action" method copy your response structure to the export parameter

```
    copy_data_to_ref(
  EXPORTING
    is_data = ls_your_response_structure
  CHANGING
    cr_data = er_data ).
```